Drupal S3fs plugin issue: Replace /path/to/publicnos3/css/optimized with the actual path to your directory
When we are upgrading Drupal from 8.9 to 9.5.11 then getting below error.
Drupal\Core\File\Exception\DirectoryNotReadyException: The specified file 'temporary://file70D54q' could not be copied because the destination directory 'publicnos3://css/optimized' is not properly configured.
noS3writeFile() issue
Seems like permission error if any one can help please?
We are also looking into it.
